# can't store when using [IF] in eloquent din't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to Store when have data in [Booking] but din't store anything to [scan]

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $event = event::findOrFail($id);
    $booking = booking::where('student_id',Auth::user()->student_id)
    ->where('name',Auth::user()->name)
    ->where('event_id',$event->id);
    if($booking!=NULL){
    $requestData = $request->all();
    scan::create($requestData);
    return redirect('event/' . $event->id .'/scan');
    return view('event.scan', compact('event','scan','booking'));
    }else{
    return redirect('event/' . $event->id .'/scan');
    }
}
```

but when using $booking==null
it store anything can't check in booking

Answer (score 3):

Your query is incomplete. It lacks of any final query method like `get()`, `first()` or `exists()`

Also you have two `return` statements inside the `if` block. Only the first will be executed, the second one will be ignored.

The correct code should be like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    $event = event::findOrFail($id);

    $booking = booking::where('student_id',Auth::user()->student_id)
    ->where('name',Auth::user()->name)
    ->where('event_id',$event->id)
    ->get(); // look this line

    if($booking!=NULL){
        $requestData = $request->all();
        scan::create($requestData);
        return redirect('event/' . $event->id .'/scan'); // I think this should not be here, right?
        return view('event.scan', compact('event','scan','booking')); // this is being ignored.
    }else{
        return redirect('event/' . $event->id .'/scan');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update your method like so. its much clearer and readable (i think anyway).

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    //use first to get a booking or use get() for collections of booking
    $booking = Booking::where('student_id', auth()->user()->student_id)
                ->where('event_id', $id)
                -first(); 

    if (is_null($booking)) {
        return redirect('event/' . $id . '/scan');
    }

    return view('event.scan', [
        'event' => Event::findOrFail($id),
        'scan' => Scan::create($request->all()),
        'booking' => $booking
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps
Cheers